# Python pandas read csv keep changing my datetime format, still happens when I specifically specify it as string or object format

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a csv file that contains two type of date time format that I will fix later on. While using the pandas' read_csv function with specified to read the column as string / str / object, it still combines both of my date-time format to Python's desired date-time format.

Below is example of my data

```
Date  Cost
3/31/2015  3363
2020-16-07  5515
```

Where I read with the following command

```
a = pd.read_csv('data.csv',dtype={'Date':object})
b = pd.read_csv('data.csv',dtype={'Date':'string'})
c = pd.read_csv('data.csv',dtype={'Date':str})
d = pd.read_csv('data.csv',converters={i: str for i in range(100)})
```

All a, b, c, d yields the same result which is the following:

```
Date  Cost
2015-3-31  3363
2020-16-07  5515
```

I've performed a dtypes check, it returns by using

```
a.dtypes
b.dtypes
c.dtypes
d.dtypes
```

All returns the same which is object for Date column

My desired output should be the same as what my data be like, so that I can pre-process and make the date-time the same format.

```
Date  Cost
3/31/2015  3363
2020-16-07  5515
```

----- Edit -----

I went and re-check my csv file with opening by using excel and re-hit save without any modification to the file, now four command yield the same result as of what I wanted. I don't know what is wrong but it works :)

However, I am still keen knowing why this happen ? This file is from cloud and all I did was save again.

--- Edit 2 ----

I've open using notepad and it was excel that is giving such a different time format not Python / Jupyter / Pandas.

Comment: What if you just do `pd.read_csv('data.csv')`?

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney it still returns the same thing as of what a, b, c, d returns.

Comment: What version of pandas? The current version is 1.1.1.

Comment: @TrentonMcKinney Hi, thank you for your time, I went and re-check my csv and I re-hit the save function without any modification by using excel, and now Python gives me the output I wanted. It is very strange

Comment: Using Jupyter Notebook?

Comment: Yes, is there any problem that may do such bug?

Comment: Have you tried opening the file in a text editor, rather than Excel? Could it be that Excel is mis-representing to you the literal strings in the csv file (aka, the March date actually appears as "2015-3-31" in the csv file")?

Comment: @relizt Omg, thank you! I tried open using notepad and it give me what jupyter returns, thank you!

Comment: Not really a problem with Jupyter so much. But objects are persistent in memory and sometimes we do something in a sell or forget to actually reload the data and, get unexpected results. Use restart kernel and clear all outputs when something seems off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(from comments discussion on the original post, copying here for good measure and future reference for others)

This can sometimes be Excel causing problems. The CSV may actually be formatted as:

```
Date  Cost
2015-3-31  3363
2020-16-07  5515
```

If you're opening it in Excel, Excel can make it appear as if the dates are formatted like `3/31/2015` and `2020-16-07` , when they actually aren't. When pandas reads the csv, it sees the literal strings without Excel's interpretation.